# Srcset displaying full size image at every screen size

Tags: css, srcset

I am trying to get the hang of using srcset for repsonsive images and have this so far..

```html
    <img
        src="https://dummyimage.com/1500x300/2a9c2a/ffffff"
        srcset="https://dummyimage.com/1200x300/2a9c2a/ffffff 1200w,
                https://dummyimage.com/992x300/2a9c2a/ffffff 992w,
                https://dummyimage.com/768x300/2a9c2a/ffffff 768w,
                https://dummyimage.com/576x300/2a9c2a/ffffff 576w"
        sizes="(max-width: 1200px) 1200px,
               (max-width: 992px) 992px,
               (max-width: 768px) 768px,
               (max-width: 576px) 576px,
               1500px
    ">
```

I am expecting it to display the `576px` wide image when my screen is below `576px`, the `768px` one when it is below `768px` and so on

It is just displaying the full size 1500px version at every screen size, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use the `picture` element if you want to deliver the pictures depending on your `viewport` .

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="https://dummyimage.com/1200x300/2a9c2a/ffffff" media="(min-width: 1200px)" />
  <source srcset="https://dummyimage.com/992x300/2a9c2a/ffffff" media="(min-width: 992px)" />
  <source srcset="https://dummyimage.com/768x300/2a9c2a/ffffff" media="(min-width: 768px)" />
  <source srcset="https://dummyimage.com/576x300/2a9c2a/ffffff" media="(min-width: 576px)" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/576x300/2a9c2a/ffffff" />
</picture>
```

Comment: That method certainly seems more human readable. Is it as supported as img?

Comment: @fightstarr20 You can use both. But in my opinion picture offers a bit more and it is supported by all. Except for IE, but there are also problems with srcset.